# Need help to get navigation bar in center with text having space around

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hover

I am new to HTM/CSS and was trying to create a navigation bar on in header, using flex and when hover it should animate underline from bottom left to right.
But I am not able to get it to be placed in center and having spaces around each item.

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>XXXXX</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </header>  
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS code:**

```
*{
    ox-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
  }

.nav a::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

 .nav a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
  }

.nav li {
    display: inline-flex;  
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

currently I am getting something like this:
|                                 About Experience Works Hobbies                                          |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf3O8.png)

I want output to be like: (having  space around)
About                Experience                Works                Hobbies

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to animate the underline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply `space-around` you need to set `display: flex;` As you can see your a elements that make up the `navbar` are inside the `ul`, which in turn is inside the `nav` class. So what you have to do is set `display: flex;` to the **direct relative** of the **elements** you want to apply it to, in this case `ul`.

```css
*{
    ox-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items:center;
  }

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
  }

.nav a::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

 .nav a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
  }

.nav li {
    display: inline-flex;  
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>XXXXX</title>
  </head>

  <body>
  <header>
      <div class="nav">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#experience">Experience</a></li>
              <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
              <li><a href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
   </header>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I get. 
Earlier I was had added the `display: flex;` under **li** , but as you said since the elements itself comes under **ul**